# Unable to start Django project in local Windows

Tags: django-allauth

[image]I am trying to run Django project in local but not able to. Getting below error in local host
Bad Request (400)

Answer (score 0):

I was not mentioning the actual URL. Its was localhost/accounts/login for this.
Its working as expected.